# how to Differentiate the kNN formula?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, k-nearest-neighbour, derivative, sum

I am going through a book on statistical learning and ran into a problem concerning k nearest neighbor methods. The book says that using least squares to determine optimal k will lead to $k=1$. I tried proving this but am not sure how to differentiate the summation part i.e $\sum_{x_{i} \epsilon N_{k}(x)} Y_{i}$ since the k is involved in the summation.

To help me out could someone show me how to differentiate the kNN formula itself with respect to k please.

Thanks!
PS the formula for kNN is:

$\frac{1}{k}\sum_{x_{i} \epsilon N_{k}(x)} Y_{i}$

Comment: Are you referring to the book *An Introduction to Statistical Learning*?

Comment: @dietervdf yes that's the book...Have you seen the proof anywhere in it?

Comment: You can't differentiate with respect to $k$, it is a positive integer, not a continuous, parameter.

Comment: @MatthewDrury You can interpret it that way but you can also view the formula as a function of k.... because I could simply interchange k and x

Comment: A solution by differentiation is posted at: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2170559/420845

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the book contains a *formal* proof, but the reasoning is as follows:

Remember that OLS aims to minimize the RSS (Residual Sum of Squares)
$$\text{RSS} = \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - f(x_i) )^2$$ 
In the case of classification, this implies the number of wrong classifications.

The kNN formula should be interpreted as averaging the categories of a circle with $k$ data-points around a certain $x_i$. If $k=1$ then each data points is categorized correctly which implies $\text{RSS} = 0$. And this is minimal.

#### 'Formal' proof

In the case of $k=1$ then the kNN formula implies for each $x_i$
$$\hat Y_i = 1 \sum_{x_j \in N_{1}(x_i)} Y_j = Y_i$$
This implies 
$$\text{RSS} = \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \hat Y_i) ^2 = 0$$

This seems good enough, since looking at the theorem '*OLS implies $k=1$*' and proving this by contradiction would result in a $k \not = 1$ as the result of OLS (and having minimal RSS). However above we noticed how $k=1$ has minimal RSS. (OLS results in unique coëfficients)

Comment: I get the reasoning but its the formal proof I want to get to.

Comment: Added a 'more formal' statement. I get you want a formal proof, but I think the reasoning is actually a proof. (I get that you don't feel like it is 'real' proof)

Comment: oooh...thanks now I see why this is enough. I guess I was expecting some differentiation